# curl: (7) Failed to connect to port 80, and 443 - on one domain

Tags: linux, apache, curl, nginx

This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear

I have checked the cURL not working properly

When I run the command `curl -I https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml`

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect

Failed to connect on all port
```

this error only on one domain, all other domain working fine, curl: (7) Failed to connect to port 80, and 443

Thanks...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After many search, I found that Hosts settings not correct

Then I check `nano /etc/hosts`
The Domain point to wrong IP in hosts file

I change the wrong IP and its working Fine

**This is new error Related to** `curl: (7) Failed to connect`

Comment: how to edit the host. my host shows 127.0.0.1 localhost and 127.0.0.1 example-virtual-machine. I dint use server block. I configure conf.d/default.conf to be my default proxy server and nothing else

Comment: can you upload what did you do in this file?

Answer (score 16):

First Check your `/etc/hosts` file entries, may be the URL which You're requesting, is pointing to your localhost.

If the URL is not listed in your `/etc/hosts` file, then try to execute following command to understand the flow of Curl Execution for the particular URL:

```
curl --ipv4 -v "https://example.com/";
```

Answer (score 5):

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect
```

The above error message means that your web-server (at least the one specified with [`curl`](http://mdoc.su/f/curl.1)) is not running at all — no web-server is running on the specified port and the specified (or implied) port.  (So, XML doesn't have anything to do with that.)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer, but this error only on one domain, all other domain working fine, `curl: (7) Failed to connect to port 80, and 443`

Comment: @Mitra So, then what's your question, again?!

Answer (score 1):

Mine is Red Hat Enterprise(RHEL) Virtual Machine and I was getting something like the following.

```
Error "curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused"
```

I stopped the firewall by running the following commands and it started working.

```
sudo systemctl stop firewalld
sudo systemctl disable firewalld
```

Comment: This resolve the same issue when I had a fresh installation of Nginx and couldn't access the default page. I got 
```sh
*   Trying <ip_address>...
* connect to <ip_address> port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to <ip_address> port 80 after 11 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection
curl: (7) Failed to connect to <ip_address> port 80 after 11 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

Just make sure the `firewalld` is not running: sudo systemctl status firewalld

Answer (score 0):

you can download the key with browser
then open terminal in downloads
then type `sudo apt-key add <key_name>.asc`

Answer (score 0):

If the `curl` is to the outside world, like:

```
curl www.google.com
```

I have to restart my cntlm service:

```
systemctl restart cntlm
```

If it's within my network:

```
curl inside.server.local
```

Then a docker network is overlapping something with my CNTLM proxy, and I just remove all docker networks to fix it - you can also just remove the last network you just created, but I'm lazy.

```
docker network rm $(docker network ls -q)
```

And then I can work again.

Answer (score 0):

It was also an /etc/hosts issue for me. I host on Amazon Lightsail, Ubuntu and Plesk. I use a dedicated IPv4 address from Lightsail. Plesk only shows the internal Amazon IPv4 address in the hosts file, even though the Plesk settings have both on one line. I manually replaced the internal Amazon IPv4 address in the hosts file with the public Amazon IPv4 address using SSH and the problem was solved immediately. I suspect that if you are using IPv6 only, this wouldn't have been a problem.