# not able to connect to internet via HTTPS minikube pods

Tags: kubernetes, dns, minikube, eclipse-che

cluster info:

[image]

Minikube installation steps on centos VM:

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/v1.21.0/minikube-linux-amd64
sudo install minikube-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube
minikube start --addons=ingress --vm=true --memory=8192 --driver=none
```

PODs of this minikube cluster are not able to connect to internet.

[image]

However My host VM has internet connection with no firewall or iptables setup.

Can anybody help me debug this connection refused error

**UPDATE:**

I have noticed just now , I am able to connect non-https URLs, but not https URLs

Answer (score 1):

How you have started the Minikube on the VM ? Which command did you used ?

If you are using the `minikube --driver=docker` it might won't work.

for starting the minikube on VM you have to change the driver

```
minikube --driver=none
```

in docker driver, it will create the container and install the kubernetes inside it and spawn the POD into further.

Check more at : https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/none/

if you on docker you can try :

```
pkill docker
iptables -t nat -F
ifconfig docker0 down
brctl delbr docker0
docker -d
```

"It will force docker to recreate the bridge and reinit all the network rules"

reference : https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/866#issuecomment-19218300

Try with

```
docker run --net=host -it ubuntu
```

Or else add dns in the config file in /etc/default/docker

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 208.67.222.222 --dns 208.67.220.220"
```

Comment: I have used --driver=none

Comment: Removing the `docker0` interface resolved temporarily my problem. I think the AWS vpn client is messing up the networking every time I connect with it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your container port and target port. This is my pod setup:

```
spec:

 containers:

       name: hello

       image: "nginx"

  ports:

      containerPort: 5000
```

This is my service setup:

```
 ports:

    protocol: TCP

        port: 60000

       targetPort: 5000
```

If your target port and container port don't match, you will get a curl: (7) connection refused error([Source](https://github.com/knative/serving/issues/7440)).

Checkout similar [Stackoverflowlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45554344/curl-7-failed-to-connect-to-port-80-and-443-on-one-domain) for more information.

Comment: Its not connecting to any web URL

Comment: I have edited my answer .Let me know if this help or you are still facing the issue.